# jenkins running under proxy -version 2.32.3

Tags: jenkins, http-proxy

I am trying to setup the jenkins running under our corporate proxy as our servers dont have direct access to internet.

However, it failed to connnect to internet to update plugins through proxy server.

Error logs:

```
ntlm authentication scheme selected
Aug 04, 2017 8:14:44 AM INFO org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector processProxyAuthChallenge
Failure authenticating with NTLM <any realm>@proxy-server:8080
```

The proxy setup as below:

[image]
Please advise>

Comment: the validation button is not working, and it is so misleading. I am still able to upgrade plugins and install new ones even though the validation button says that the proxy is not working.

Answer (score 0):

i am able to solve this problem by upgrading to the latest version **2.60.2**